# How to edit the kernel files using yocto recipe

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, openembedded

I am using yocto krogoth branch and compiling kernel image. Now i want to change some data in the middle of the this `drivers/tty/serial/imx.c`.
using `yocto recipe without git patches`. could you please give me some inputs.

Comment: That seems inappropriate. Yocto is not meant for that. But still you can your own functionality to change some files of the Linux kernel using python within your recipe or bbclass file as a task. Something named `do_edit_kernel` and add this task using `add task do_edit_kernel after do_kernel_configme before do_compile`. But editing means changing something to source code always, thats why we have `do_patch`

Comment: I dont know about krogoth, but my workflow for  versions >pyro is entering the devshell of the kernel, creating a patch via quilt, modifiying what i want and finally add the patch into the recipe. It is automatically incorptorated in the do_patch step, mentioned by @Parthiban

Answer (score 0):

Patching with quilt is the way to go:

https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#using-a-quilt-workflow