# Yocto - Adding drivers to kernel source using a recipe without patching and branching

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, yocto, petalinux

I have developed some specific kernel built in drivers for my ZYNQ7000 device and I would like to make them inside the kernel source every time I update the kernel version (updating the `petalinux` version).

As far as I know, the most common ways to add the built in module are creating a git branch then add my driver sources or creating patches. Since my drivers are independent from others in the kernel source, I would like to add the driver sources to the kernel sources in `kernel_%.bbappend` (from `recipes-kernel`). Are there any ways/methods I could this to archieve the same effect as the common ways? Thanks.

**Extra info:** From [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53113672/how-to-edit-the-kernel-files-using-yocto-recipe) I see that I can add a task to modify the kernel source using `python`, but I wonder if there are any easier ways to do this.